# Stop multiple ListCell Context Menus from Showing

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I made a Custom ListView Cell so i can add a Context Menu but it keeps opening multiple context menus when you click more than once and the old ones just raise Exceptions when used.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my SongCell class

```
public SongCell(ListView<Song> list, Playlist playlist) {

    setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

    ContextMenu listContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    MenuItem removeItem = new MenuItem("Remove");
    MenuItem editID3Item = new MenuItem("Edit ID3");
    MenuItem playNextItem = new MenuItem("Play Next");
    removeItem.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {

        list.getItems().remove(getIndex());

    });

    editID3Item.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        Optional<Pair<String, String>> show = new FXID3Edit(getItem()).show();
    });
    playNextItem.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        Song song = getItem();
        list.getItems().remove(song);
        playlist.addSongRequest(new SongRequest(song, SongRequest.type.NEXT));
    });

    listContextMenu.getItems().add(removeItem);
    listContextMenu.getItems().add(playNextItem);
    listContextMenu.getItems().add(editID3Item);

    setOnMousePressed(event -> {
        if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY)) {

            if (getItem() != null) {

                if (getItem().equals(playlist.getSong())) {
                    playNextItem.setDisable(true);
                    removeItem.setDisable(true);
                } else {
                    playNextItem.setDisable(false);
                    removeItem.setDisable(false);
                }
                listContextMenu.show(list, event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
            }

        }

        if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY) && event.getClickCount() == 2) {
            playlist.setIndex(this.getIndex());
            playlist.play();

        }

        event.consume();
    });

}
@Override
protected void updateItem(Song item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (!empty && item != null) {
        this.setText(item.toString());
    } else {
        this.setText("");
    }
}
```

I also greatly appreciate help on my Coding Style

Comment: Since there is no problem with the context menus in JavaFX, I guess your problem resolves itself once you fix the exceptions.

Comment: I don't mind the exceptions because i only want 1 ContextMenu to show up at a time.

Comment: The context menus staying open could be because of the Exceptions ...

Comment: The exceptions happen when you try to use the old context menus

Comment: Do you need to consume the event? It's vaguely possible that is preventing the existing context menu from "knowing" that it should hide...

Comment: scratch that. i need to hide every other context menu before calling the new one. it doesn't do that on it's own. every cell has it's own instance of context menu.

Comment: You can try calling `listContextMenu.setAutoHide(true);`, though I think this is the default value for that property anyway. Did you try removing `event.consume()` to see if it made a difference?

Comment: Removing `event.consume()` doesn't help and `setAutoHide(true)` doesn't change anything. Appreciate your help either way.

Comment: OK, found two solutions. The better one is to use the `contextMenu` property: see answer. But you can also make the owner of the context menu the `ListCell` instead of the `ListView`: i.e. just change your current `listContextMenu.show(...)` call to `listContextMenu.show(this, event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of registering a mouse listener to show the context menu, use the built-in `setContextMenu(...)` property. I.e.:

```
public SongCell(ListView<Song> list, Playlist playlist) {

    // ...

    setOnMousePressed(event -> {

        if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY) && event.getClickCount() == 2) {
            playlist.setIndex(this.getIndex());
            playlist.play();

        }

        event.consume();
    });

}

@Override
public void updateItem(Song item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (!empty && item != null) {
        this.setText(item.toString());
        this.setContextMenu(listContextMenu);
    } else {
        this.setText("");
        this.setContextMenu(null);
    }
}
```